# mobile design from a laptop

Tags: css, mobile

I need to put together a mobile version of my site, but I don't have
an iPhone, all I have is this MacbookPro w/Lion, 17-inch.

All I have is this laptop. How do I go about building a mobile
version of my site? I'm looking for general suggestions; thanks.

Comment: resize your browser window and design accordingly

Comment: @sachleen, screen size isn't the problem with mobiles, their rending engines differ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some really good mobile emulators to help you developing a mobile website:

- http://iphone4simulator.com/
- http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

Using those emulators should enable you to design and develop a quite good mobile website.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous tools, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View that help you emulate mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

An iPhone wouldn't be enough either. You would have to test many phones. :)

In general, you can do a lot of testing by making your browser window smaller. This will at least trigger the CSS media queries and you can test if they work.

There are also many tools online that either are almust full emulators, or are just sites that check for common errors. [Take a look at 10 excellent tools for testing mobile sites](http://sixrevisions.com/tools/10-excellent-tools-for-testing-your-site-on-mobile-devices/).